# Ruby render error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I work with faye railscast and have error in view:

```
<%= render @messages %>
```

and error:

```
'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path.
```

What does this means? <%= @messages %> works, but with render doesnt.

Comment: it means `@messages` is nil where as it is expecting object of the some model class

Comment: `<%= @messages %>` means put out value of the @messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is telling you that `@messages` is `nil`. When calling

```
<%= render @messages %>
```

`render` is expecting an *ActiveModel-compatible* object.

You need to check how `@messages` is created in your controller.

Comment: ok thanks ... first time i see error like this when object is nil

Comment: You welcome, consider accepting the answer if you think it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for collection rendering, But for that @messages should by array of objects of Message Model.

You can check this

```
<% unless @messages.blank? %>
 <%= render @messages %>
<%end%>
```

Comment: I think `@messages` should not be `nil` in the first place. At least an empty array, but this case will not raise an error.

Comment: yeah thats why I gave him suggestion in first line.